# Is all of Afghanistan dangerous for travellers?

Tags: safety, security, extreme-tourism, war-zones, afghanistan

Recently I have read a few travel books to get some inspiration for the next long summer journey. I was especially reading Lonely Planet travel guides. I was a little bit surprised that they very often described Afghanistan as a destination. I always thought that there is war. Maybe Lonely Planet isn't as anxious as other travel guides might be, but objectively, what would I have to expect when traveling to Afghanistan? And is it possible at all?

Comment: See also my older question about Iraq: [Are some parts of Iraq currently possible to visit for the brave, adventurous, and open-minded traveller?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/are-some-parts-of-iraq-currently-possible-to-visit-for-the-brave-adventurous-a)

Comment: I'm pretty sure people are travelling the hippie trail again (Europe to India overland) and it's a case of "some parts are very dangerous but not everywhere is dangerous", just like anywhere in the world but amplified a lot!

Comment: I watered down your question a bit to imply that some bits might have different levels of safety than other bits - hope you don't mind - you can revert it if you disagree.

Comment: No problem, that's better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In July I was in Tajikistan, along the Afghanistan border.  I met a LOT of travellers going there.  Indeed, the Central Asia Lonely Planet (English version) has a picture of a temple from within Afghanistan.

It was sooo tempting.

However, due to a [slight medical emergency](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/983/warfarin-in-tajikistan), I had to backtrack from Khorog along the Afghanistan border again to Dushanbe and leave from there.  Otherwise I'd totally have gone across for a few days.

[image: The road to Khorog from Dushanbe, Afghanistan across the river on the right]

So why are people going? For the [Wakhan Corridor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakhan_Corridor) - a sliver of land perfect for trekking, and well away from the war-zones.  It's considered pretty safe, but again, you'd need to check your insurance as you may not be covered there.

However, anywhere west of Fayzabad and you're starting to get into dangerous territory.  Very.  One Dutch traveller I met had a police escort at a point and heard explosions.  It's still dangerous.

And really, if the Taliban decides to branch out and start kidnapping tourists in the Wakhan Corridor, it may change.  It's a very volatile place.

However, if you go to Khorog, there's an Afghanistan embassy on the south side of the river in town, open from 9am.  You can get a visa for Afghanistan within 24 hours.

It's important to make sure you have a visa and entry for the Tajikistan side when you return, however, as if you need to get a new visa in Afghanistan, all embassies will be in Kabul.  And you don't want to have to travel there if you don't want to.

Of course, it all depends how crazy you are. I also met two Russians who had hitchhiked from Moscow to Tajikstan and were continuing on to Kabul.  It's entirely possible, just not guaranteed.

Comment: i wouldn't use this picture to promote travels to Afghanistan, because quite honest, it looks as charming and inviting as an stone quarry or open pit coal mine. Just sayin'...

Comment: Really? To me it was thrilling and 'out there'! I loved it :D

Comment: @iHaveacomputer I disagree, it looks tempting

Comment: agree it looks fabulous.

Comment: enhanced your picture with an appropriate caption: http://imgur.com/SAcNB :D

Comment: This is still valid in 2012; I was there in July this year.

Answer (score 2):

I have a friend who lives in Afghanistan and he swears it's safe, and that there is no Taliban or other psycho group in the very northern parts where he lives. He says they (his community/village/whatever) don't allow that crap. Maybe he's talking it up, but I tend to believe him.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. This may be true, but it is an anecdote, rather than a statistic, and the latter would be more useful if you can find them— number of foreign visitors handled, availability of tourist services, prevalence of crime or political violence, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to travel to Afghanistan.

Not all of Afghanistan is dangerous - there are areas which are relatively safe to visit and a very small number of intrepid travelers pay them visits. There are now even European travel companies which are specializing adventure tours to Afghanistan.  [Untamed Borders](http://www.untamedborders.com/), a UK travel company offers adventure tours to Afghanistan as well as Ski and snowboarding holidays. [Check this link about Afghanistan Skiing.](http://www.powdermania.com/index.php?skiing-afghanistan)

Comment: I notice you posted two links to untamedborders in minutes.  Are you affiliated with the site?  It's fine if you are, but we do ask that you indicate as such.